# Format an X axys in Rickshaw starting at 0ms and evolving from ms to seconds automatically

Tags: rickshaw

I'm using rickshaw to plot the evolution of a genetic algorithm along time. So I would like to  feed the chart in streaming and see the time in x-Axys starting at 0s.

I'm currently using dynamic pushing of streamed results like:

```
var data = { x: new Date().getTime(), y: N) };
graph.series[0].data.push(data);
graph.render();
```

And I'm configuring the x-Axys like this:

```
var axes = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Time({
  graph: graph
} );
```

The result I achieve is a timeline with strange times on it, like 45, then 02:00, then 13:00.
What I need was  something like

    `______________ 
    |     |     |

    0s    1s    2s`

evolving to 

    `________________ 
    |     |     |

    0s    5s    10s`

Any one has some tips?

Answer (score 1):

I just found one possible answer.

```
// Declare the starting time
var startTime = new Date().getTime();

// format time to appear only the seconds
var format = function(d) {
  d = new Date(d);

  var seconds = Number(d3.time.format("%S")(d));
  if (seconds === 0) {
    return Number(d3.time.format("%L")(d)) + ' ms';
  } else {
    return seconds + ' s';
  }
};

var x_axis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.X({
  graph: graph,
  tickFormat: format,
});

// Push new value
// Subtract startTime to the current time
var currTime = new Date().getTime() - startTime;
var data = { x: currTime, y: N) };
graph.series[0].data.push(data);

// Render the graph
graph.render();
```

You can check more time formats in D3 in this link: http://www.d3noob.org/2012/12/formatting-date-time-on-d3js-graph.html